# How to fetch files from directory based on file name pattern is numeric?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to fetch files from a directory, my criteria is file name must be **numeric**.

This is my code:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(0|[1-9][0-9]+)$");
var file_list = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\download\", "*.xml").Where(p => reg.IsMatch(p)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(file_list.Count);
```

There are 7 matching files but my output is 0. Please help me to solve this. Thanks

Comment: `reg.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p))`

Comment: Thanks very much @WiktorStribiżew it worked